# Implement order definition by multiple attributes

Tags: python, sorting, oop

I'd like to know how to efficiently sort by object's multiple attributes. For instance, given

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.a == other.a:
            return self.b < other.b
        return self.a < other.a


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.a}, {self.b})'

A1 = A(1, 5)
A2 = A(2, 5)
A3 = A(1, 6)
A4 = A(4, 0)
A5 = A(-3, -3)
A6 = A(0, 7)

l = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6]
```

The expected order of class A instances after sorting is
`A5, A6, A1, A3, A2, A4`, i.e.

```
A(-3, -3)
A(0, 7)
A(1, 5)
A(1, 6)
A(2, 5)
A(4, 0)
```

because I want to order by both attributes `a` and `b` values.
However, with the increasing number of attributes the logic relying on embedded conditional statements, e.g.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.a == other.a:
            if self.b == other.b:
                return self.c < other.c
            return self.b < other.b
        return self.a < other.a
```

seems to be cumbersome.

Do you have a better idea to implement such a sorting for a custom object? I was expecting the short circuit to do the trick:

```
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a < other.a or self.b < other.b
```

but it generated following order:

```
A(-3, -3)
A(0, 7)
A(4, 0)
A(1, 5)
A(1, 6)
A(2, 5)
```

which is not what I want.

Comment: You ask about sorting, but you're not actually sorting, you're just defining an order. If you were actually sorting, there'd be something more efficient than the accepted answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy, good point. I'll edit the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python sequences are ordered in the same way you want your objects ordered (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types), so you can co-opt that mechanism for your use case.  For example:

```py
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c) < (other.a, other.b, other.c)
```

Comment: Maybe noteworthy: if they were actually sorting, with `sorted` or `list.sort`, then it would be more efficient to use a `key` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(order=True)
class A:
    a: int
    b: int
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the logic you are describing I think it'd make sense to set a canonical importance order somewhere (ie. make it explicit that things are sorted in the `a`, `b`, `c`, order...)

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        
        self._ordered_attrs = ['a','b','c']
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        for attr in self._ordered_attrs:
            if getattr(self, attr) != getattr(other, attr):
                return getattr(self, attr) < getattr(other, attr)
            
        return False
```

This implements the same logic you were describing, but as a loop over the attributes.